# font size and color using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've been stuck for a day on this problem.
i'm trying to change the font color of my variable.
Let me give you an idea on my code below:

```
var add = 10 + 10;
var minus = 10 + 10;

var total = add + minus;

$('#output').html(total + ' is the answer')
```

i tried using the following to no avail:

```
total.style.color = "red";
```

**i would like to change the font color of "total" and not including 'is the answer'**
i hope someone can help me on this. thank you all.

Comment: If you want to format the total different to the rest, place inside a `<span>`, and add the style to that instead.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are applying the `style` to a variable but you need to apply it to the DOM element.

```js
var add = 10 + 10;
var minus = 10 + 10;

var total = add + minus;

$('#output').html(total).css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="output">...</span>
```

Comment: its working thanks.. but i had some few edits on my question above. please see sir.

Comment: nevermind sir.. i found a way. and yes your solution works on my first question. thank you sir!

Answer (score 2):

```
var add = 10 + 10;
var minus = 10 + 10;

var total = add + minus;

$('#output').html(`<span>${total}</span>` + ' is the answer');
$('#output span').css('color','red');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/dpenm8fy/2/

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change the font color of your "total" variable.

In vanilla JS,if you want to change the font color, you have to get the element object and then change it. For example, if I have this html:

```
<div id = "something"> some text <div/>
```

in JS, I would have to grab the div object which has id = "something" and then change its attributes, hence,

```
var something = document.getElementById("something");

something.style.color = "red";
```

So, for your case, I see you have the id name as "#output" and you're setting the HTML content with jQuery, if were to select it in Vanilla JS you have to grab the tag from DOM which has id = "output" and change its attributes:

```
var output = document.getElementById("output");
output.style.color = "green";
```

For jQuery

```
$('#output').html(50 + ' is the answer').css('color', 'green')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var add = 10 + 10;
var minus = 10 + 10;
var total = add + minus;
$("#output").html(total);
$("#output").css({'color': 'red'});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var add = 10 + 10;
var minus = 10 + 10;
$('#output').html(add+minus).css('color', 'green');
```